# How to evenly space HTML 'th' elements with a fixed parent?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table as per below:

```
<table class='table table-striped jambo_table'>
 <thead>
 <tr class='headings'>
  <th class='column-title'>Campaign ID </th>
  <th class='column-title'>Campaign Name </th>
  <th class='column-title'>Type </th>
  <th class='column-title no-link last'><span class='nobr'>Status</span></th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
.... Other stuff
</table>
```

The 'tr' element with the class 'headings' is fixed.

```
.headings {
  position: fixed;
  top:200px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  left:250px;
  right:0;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

This causes the th elements to be unevently spaced.

E.g:  It should look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

How can I make the th elements evenly spaced?

Comment: could you try setting a ```width:100%;``` to ```.headings```?

Comment: `table{width:100%;}` might do it. Just make sure the parent element has a width.

Answer (score 3):

#### Add this:

> ```
> html,
> body {
>   height: 100%;
>   width: 100%;
> }
>
> table {
>   width: 100%;
>   table-layout: fixed;
> }
>
> th {
>   width: 25%
> }
> ```

**Note:** The `top`, `left`, and `right` properties are set to 0 for the demo, but you can set them as before with no ill effects.

#### Snippet

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  width: 20%
}

.headings {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table class='table table-striped jambo_table'>
  <thead>
    <tr class='headings'>
      <th class='column-title'>Campaign ID </th>
      <th class='column-title'>Campaign Name </th>
      <th class='column-title'>Type </th>
      <th class='column-title no-link last'><span class='nobr'>Status</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```