# Divs not spacing evenly with margins

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am having trouble evenly spacing my divs for Projects, Videos, Portfolios and Contact using margins. I wanted it to start even spacing from the right of the screen. But I didn't use pixel values for spacing because I wanted to avoid hardcoded numbers as much as possible. I also realize that the way I have designed the nav-bar isn't the most efficient.

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.title-bar {
  height: 14%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.title-icon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.title-links {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.title-1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 45%;
}

.title-2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

.title-3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.title-4 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.title-link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title-link:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 63, 145);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="title-icon">
    <h3>Rupak Y</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="title-links">
    <div class="title-1">
      <a class="title-link" href="#">
        <h3>Projects</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="title-2">
      <a class="title-link" href="#">
        <h3>Videos</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="title-3">
      <a class="title-link" href="#">
        <h3>Portfolio</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="title-4">
      <a class="title-link" href="#">
        <h3>Contact</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to evenly space the each of the five words across your screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** ever use `position: absolute` for situations like this. This can be done a lot easier and with less CSS:

Use `display: flex` both on the container and the links div, add `margin-left: auto` to the links div to align it right and add some margins to the single links to create a distance between them (I used 3vw margin-left, a unit relative to the viewport width). Also, apply `display: block` to the `a` tags to make them behave as blocks, and use left and right `padding` on the container to create the offset of the texts at the left and right side.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.title-bar {
  display: flex;
  height: 14%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 3%;
}

.title-links {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.title-link {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 3vw;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title-link:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 63, 145);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <div class="title-icon">
    <h3>Rupak Y</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="title-links">
    <div class="title-1">
      <a class="title-link" href="#">
        <h3>Projects</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="title-2">
      <a class="title-link" href="#">
        <h3>Videos</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="title-3">
      <a class="title-link" href="#">
        <h3>Portfolio</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="title-4">
      <a class="title-link" href="#">
        <h3>Contact</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the table tag I adapted from the zer00ne's answer from the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508968/how-to-evenly-space-html-th-elements-with-a-fixed-parent) question.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  width: 20%
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rupak Yeware - Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class='table table-striped jambo_table'>
          <th class='column-title' style="color:white">Rupak Y</th>
          <th class='column-title' style="color:white"><a href="#;">Projects</a></th>
          <th class='column-title' style="color:white"><a href="#;">Videos</a></th>
          <th class='column-title' style="color:white"><a href="#;">Portfolio</a></th>
          <th class='column-title no-link last' style="color:white"><span class='nobr'><a href="#;">Contact</a></span></th>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using a column for each of your headers and then evenly spacing them by 20% will allow you keep them all evenly spaced. If you ever add more headers, obviously you need to adjust the percentage they are spaced by.

Here is more information about the table tag:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp